# Jquery if keydown and keyup event trigger disable other keypress events works in Chrome not in IE & Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

As i'm creating autosuggestions text box but i'm facing issue as when keydown and keyup trigger then it is also triggering keypress event in Mozilla and IE But it works fine in Chrome.

```js
$(".search-terms").on("keypress", function(){
  $("#notice").html("Searching");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Search items you want to exchange" autocomplete="off" name="resultsFor" class="search-terms">
<div id="notice">Ready to search</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain better your issue?

Comment: please run snippet in chrome and try to press keydown and keyup u will not able to see Searching label below text box but it will be visible in Mozilla and IE

Comment: Means it is working fine in Chrome fine but not in IE & Mozilla

Comment: In firefox i can see the searching label and in chrome i can't, you don't want it to trigger the keypress event in firefox?

Comment: yes @RamSegev and even in IE. But keyup and keydown event has to trigger

Comment: Sorry, but on my computer (windows 10) with last version of Chrome, FF and IE I don't see any difference.

Comment: @gaetanoM im using Windows 7 facing issue

Comment: @IqbalPasha So the problem is Windows 7. Believe me on Windows 10 I don't see any problem. I don't have windows 7 so I cannot help. In any case its good to know....

Comment: Thats ok @gaetanoM thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have found the issue debugging it like this

```js
$(".search-terms").keypress(function( event ) {
  $("#notice").html(event.keyCode);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Search items you want to exchange" autocomplete="off" name="resultsFor" class="search-terms">
<div id="notice">Ready to search</div>
```

As you can see you get the keycode value, when using the same code in chrome nothing happens but in firefox for the arrows keys you get values from 37-40. So with using if statement you can decide what to do with if, here is an example

```js
$(".search-terms").keypress(function( event ) {
//$("#notice").html(event.keyCode);
if (event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40) 
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
    $("#notice").html("Searching");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Search items you want to exchange" autocomplete="off" name="resultsFor" class="search-terms">
<div id="notice">Ready to search</div>
```